# ClassNotFoundException during Weblogic 12c Java 1.8 EE app deployment while jars are there

Tags: classnotfoundexception, weblogic12c, hibernate-5.x, dom4j, java-ee-8

I have a Java EE application that runs properly on my local Weblogic instance, but throws seems to be Hibernate 5 related exceptions. The most recent was

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.io.STAXEventReader
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43)
at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init>(MetadataSources.java:86)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:123)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:118)
at no.oslokommune.boligbygg.takst.database.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:28)
at no.oslokommune.boligbygg.takst.database.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:22)
at no.oslokommune.boligbygg.takst.service.BeregningServiceBean.getBeregningsByMatrisePeriode(BeregningServiceBean.java:49)
at no.oslokommune.boligbygg.takst.service.BeregningService_8gm1tc_EOImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:34)
at no.oslokommune.boligbygg.takst.service.BeregningService_8gm1tc_EOImpl.getBeregningsByMatrisePeriode(Unknown Source)
at no.oslokommune.boligbygg.takst.service.BeregningService_8gm1tc_EOImpl_CBV.getBeregningsByMatrisePeriode(Unknown Source)
at no.oslokommune.boligbygg.takst.view.action.BeregnLeieprisHistoryListAction.execute(BeregnLeieprisHistoryListAction.java:66)
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:247)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3650)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3620)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2423)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2258)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1626)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1586)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:617)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:397)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

The *dom4j-2.1.1.jar* is included in the package and I can literally find the class in the lib folder under *MyApp.ear* package.

It seems like the classpath that is used on the on-premise Weblogic server is not getting updated. I guess it's the Weblogic's internal libs that collide.

I tried deleting tmp folder from the server subfolder, restarting, redeploying etc.

How can I make sure the right logging library is used?

Comment: Is that jar file under WEB-INF/lib or APP-INF, or at the root of the ear file?

Comment: The jar is under {root}/lib

Comment: try moving to inside war file at WEB-INF/lib

Comment: That jar is only used under the ejb.jar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384899/reasons-to-use-web-inf-lib-over-ears-lib

Comment: And WEB-INF has nothing to do with a EJB module as I understand